# kfd kfd: kgd2kfd_probe failed

Tags: boot, 20.04, hard-drive, ram, cleanup

I am new to Ubuntu .
I just cleaned up the computer and when I wanted to start it , it won’t start .when I checked , one of the rams was not in his place, but it’s not working .Takes forever to boot , I can’t enter the recovery mode .
I will try to fix it myself , if someone can help me , that would be great ! Thank you !
[in the photo you can see the errors I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejV2G.jpg)

I have the latest version of Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS.
I’ve been trying to reinstall from the usb that I used to install it in the first time , but it did not work.
Every time when I restart the pc , I have like 10 min “_” and after that I have the logo “AORUS” and after that I’ve got an error “ bad rip value” .
Thanks for the answer and I hope that you can understand what I am writing .

Comment: Hi and welcome. You need to give some information in order to help you. What version of Ubuntu? What did you try to fix it? Do not give pictures of text include it in the question.

Comment: Please include the information in the question as an edit. Sounds like the USB is bad. I suggest you download a fresh ISO and make a new live USB.

Comment: I’ve had the same errors even with a fresh usb ! 
Instead I opened the case , I got out the ram sticks and put them back! And I reinstall the Ubuntu server easy , without any problem ! 
Thank you for your help .